# SQL Update Inserted from Trigger

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm using MS-SQL I'm trying to create a trigger which keeps legacy document in sync.

I have this statement at the top of the file which will remove document Id's from company bank accounts who do not have a filepath associated with them

```
UPDATE CompanyBankAccounts
SET SignatureDocumentId = NULL
FROM CompanyBankAccounts cba
INNER JOIN INSERTED i on cba.CompanyBankAccountID = i.CompanyBankAccountID
WHERE (i.SignatureFile IS NULL OR i.SignatureFile = '') 
AND i.SignatureDocumentId IS NOT NULL
```

However after I go on to do more operations on which rely on the Inserted Table e.g

```
IF (
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Inserted i
    LEFT JOIN Documents d on d.documentid = i.SignatureDocumentId
    WHERE (SignatureFile IS NOT NULL AND SignatureFile != '')
    AND ((SignatureFile != d.DocumentPath) OR SignatureDocumentId IS NULL)
) > 0)
BEGIN 
--Do Sync work
END
```

After the Initial Update Statement the Inserted Rows will now still have documentIds, is there a way to be assured that the inserted rows appropiately reflect the changes made from the update?

Comment: FYI `UPDATE CompanyBankAccounts` should really be `UPDATE cba`. SQL Server should be clever enough to realise that the new reference to `CompanyBankAccounts` is the same one, but it's good habit.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, I don't write SQL that often so those little tips help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
> and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
> rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
> rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
> table.
>
> An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an
> insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first,
> and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the
> inserted table.

The 'inserted' table contains copies of the affected rows and it's purpose is to extend the referential integrity, etc. of DML actions.  As such it's the correct place for  your trigger to access the affected rows.

Comment: Thanks,  I'm aware the inserted rows are copies.  But If I do an Update inside the trigger, then continue on to operate on the INSERTED the INSERTED will be out of sync still. e.g Since it's a copy it still contains the old values, how do I get around that?

Comment: It's possible to call triggers recursively and to address them logically by level of recursion.  Are you sure you want to go down that path?  The trigger has to ask itself what level of recursion am I? then deal with it.  I recommend to re-write your transaction and remove the trigger using the OUTPUT clause of the UPDATE statement.  Then run it in a loop if it's required

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: If you add to the question I'll take a shot at it